# Ruby Activerecord query compare with range

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have to query for a user who needs to manage a dossier.
The user has a min and a max field and if the last number of the dossier number is between those 2 values the user needs to be found.
This is the other way round most queries between a range work.

For the moment I have to use plain sql, the following works but I would like to use an activerecord query (the first error) or at least a safer method (second error).

For better readability I shortened the names of the fields.

```
dosnr = 123456
# error invalid identifier
# User.where(dosnr.to_s[-1] => :min..:max ) 

# error invalid character 6
# User.where("#{dosnr.to_s[-1]} between ? and ?, min, max ") 

# sql works
User.where("#{dosnr.to_s[-1]} between min and max ")
```

How to do this without using the sql or without having to loop all the records or having to use multiple where statements ?

Comment: `dosnr` is a column in users table? What's the data type? I believe there's no such a way of doing it in activerecord, which SQL you're using?

Comment: no dosnr is a variable, the sql is the last line

Comment: Does that mean min and max are columns and you need to find all users b/w min and max from the last integer of dosnr variable??

Comment: @Surua yes it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to do it without SQL, because ActiveRecord doesn't support built-in methods for '<', '>' or 'BETWEEN' operators at the current moment. But you can rid of string interpolation, which is unsafe:

```
User.where('? between min and max', dosnr.to_s[-1])
```

Comment: Query is incorrect. For `dosnr = 123456` it will translate to `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE 6 BETWEEN min and max`, That's not desired result.

Comment: @Surya I don't think so.

Comment: Don't take my word for it, try it yourself.

Comment: @Ilya: You're right. I read it on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between, I missed it completely.

Comment: This can also be written as `User.where('? % 10 BETWEEN min and max', dosnr)`